# iOS in app purchase credit for physical goods

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I am creating an app for a bar, I wish to allow users to purchase credits on to the app and then spend these credits at the bar which will be relative to the money cost. Similar function to the Starbucks app.

Dose anyone know of a good gateway I could do this with? I'm finding it hard to establish whether or not you can turn the user's payments into credit in the app to then use.

What do you guys think?

Comment: You can user Stripe or Braintree

Comment: You could just use in-app purchases

Comment: @mhillsman No you can't. Not for physical goods.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

11.3 & 11.4

> 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected
>
> 11.4 Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the App

Souns like you must not / cannot do that with in-app purchases.